# Help I don't know how to handle this error (java.lang.RuntimeException: EMBEDDED Broker start failure:code = 1)

Tags: java, glassfish

I follow this tutorial (http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest-mysql.html) and it's success, but when i try with my database, it become error. I already follow step by step , but still error, anyone know how to handle this error? or it's bug too?

> MQJMSRA_RA4001:
>   start:Aborting:Exception starting
>   EMBEDDED broker=EMBEDDED Broker start
>   failure:code = 1
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: EMBEDDED
>   Broker start failure:code = 1
>           at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EmbeddedBrokerRunner.start(EmbeddedBrokerRunner.java:268)
>           at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter.start(ResourceAdapter.java:472)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Apparently, this happens when you change your server IP address and the lock file keeps the old IP. Simply delete the lock file:
\imq\instances\imqbroker\lock

Source:
http://old.nabble.com/Glassfish-V2-failed-to-start,-broker%3Dembedded,-failure:code-%3D-1-td17728741.html

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6706146) in GF. Probably upgrade to later GF version will help.

Comment: I can't find a replacement at the moment, but the link is outdated.